# Create a cursor with multiple items in selectionArgs for a single db Column

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a cursor loader where I want to query a specific Column for two items, similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN(something, something_else);

return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                myUri,
                null,
                MyContract.FoodEntry.COLUMN_TYPE + " = ? ",
                selectionArgs,
                null);
```

Not sure how the selectionArgs (which is a String array) should look like. Is there any way to achieve what I want with this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `LIKE` keyword and use `%` to specify wildcards on either side of `something` and `something_else`.

Also, you should probably use instance variables to store the two Strings, as I'm not sure how you would pass them into `onCreateLoader()`.

I just tested this by querying the contacts on my device, it will give you an idea of how to use the `selectionArgs`.

Note that for each `?` in the `selection` parameter, you will need a corresponding String in the `selectionArgs`

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String s1 = "Dan";
        String s2 = "nugent";
        String[] selectionArgs = {"%" + s1 + "%" , "%"  + s2 + "%" };
        return new CursorLoader(this, CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ? OR " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?", selectionArgs, null);
    }
```

See [Documentation Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#CursorLoader(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)).

So for your specific example, it would be something like this:

```
    String[] selectionArgs =  {"%" + something + "%" , "%"  + something_else + "%" };
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            myUri,
            null,
            MyContract.FoodEntry.COLUMN_TYPE + " LIKE ? OR " +  MyContract.FoodEntry.COLUMN_TYPE + " LIKE ?",
            selectionArgs,
            null);
```

Also, just in case this helps, this is how I retrieved the values in my test:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            res.append("\n" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY)));

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        textView.setText(res);
    }

}
```

Also I had the Activity implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
```